# How Can I Save This Array of Images?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, tags

I'm very new to programming, and I jumped right into a project (I know thats not the smartest thing to do, but I'm learning as I go). The app that I'm writing has 10 UIImageViews that display a picture from the users camera roll. The code I'm using needs each of the UIImageViews to have tags. I'm currently using NSData to save the array images, and it works great, but I can't use this method anymore because NSData doesn't support the use of tags. I also can't use NSUserDefaults, because I can't save images to a plist. Here is how I'm attempting to do this (using the NSData method, which works but I have to edit this so that my tags work.)

This is my current code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
    if (imageView.image == nil) {
        imageView.image = img;

        [self.array addObject:imageView.image];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;

    }

    if (imageView2.image == nil) {
        imageView2.image = img;
        NSLog(@"The image is a %@", imageView);
        [self.array addObject:imageView2.image];

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        return;
    }
    ...


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
    NSLog(@"Image on didenterbackground: %@", imageView);

    [self.array addObject:imageView.image];
    [self.array addObject:imageView2.image];

    [self.user setObject:self.array forKey:@"images"];
    [user synchronize];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSLog(@"It is %@", self.user);
    self.array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];
    imageView.image = [[self.array objectAtIndex:0] copy];
    imageView2.image = [[self.array objectAtIndex:1] copy];    

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                               object:app];

    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Any help or suggestions on how to edit this code so that I can save the images, while using tags is much appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT: Here is my updated code:**

```
       -(IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    for (UIImageView *imageView in self.array) {

        NSInteger tag = self.imageView.tag;
        UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",tag];

        NSString *imagePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    }
NSLog(@"Saved Button Pressed");
}



- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {

}


-(void)viewDidLoad {

    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *docFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docsDir error:NULL];

    for (NSString *fileName in docFiles) {

        if ([fileName hasSuffix:@".png"]) {
            NSString *fullPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];

            if (!imageView.image) {
                imageView.image = loadedImage;
            } else {
                imageView2.image = loadedImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set the tag in the file name of the image

Comment: @Otium Ah really? That would be perfect, how could I do that? Sorry for the movie question.

Comment: Just wondering ... is there a reason you are not using Core Data?

Comment: Probably because he said he's very new to programming in obj-c and CoreData is a difficult concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use "Fast Enumeration" to parse the array's objects, and write each object to disk  sequentially. First, you're going to need to add the UIImageView objects to the array instead of the UIImage property of the UIImageView, so you can recover the tag.  So instead of writing

```
[self.array addObject:imageView.image];
```

It will be

```
[self.array addObject:imageView];
```

Try to follow along with my code. I inserted comments on each line to help.

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //Obtain the documents directory
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainmask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    //begin fast enumeration
    //this is special to ObjC: it will iterate over any array one object at a time
    //it's easier than using for (i=0;i<array.count;i++)
    for (UIImageView *imageView in self.array) {
        //get the imageView's tag to append to the filename
        NSInteger tag = imageView.tag;
        //get the image from the imageView;
        UIImage *image = imageView.image;
        //create a filename, in this case "ImageTAGNUM.png"
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",tag];
        //concatenate the docsDirectory and the filename
        NSString *imagePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

To load the images from disk, you'll have to look at your viewDidLoad method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    //get the contents of the docs directory
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainmask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    //Get the list of files from the file manager
    NSArray *docFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docsDir error:NULL]);
    //use fast enumeration to iterate the list of files searching for .png extensions and load those
    for (NSString *fileName in docFiles) {
        //check to see if the file is a .png file
        if ([fileName hasSuffix:@".png"]) {
            NSString *fullPath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            UIImage *loadedImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
            //you'll have to sort out how to put these images in their proper place
            if (!imageView1.image) {
                imageView1.image = loadedImage;
            } else {
                imageView2.image = loadedImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

One thing you need to be aware of is that when an app enters the background it has about 5 seconds to clean up its act before it's suspended. The UIPNGRepresentation() function takes a significant amount of time and is not instantaneous.  You should be aware of this.  It would probably be better to write some of this code in other places and do it earlier than at app backgrounding.  FWIW

Comment: Thank you so much, that was tremendously helpful. I do have an issue or two though, only the first image, imageView, gets saved. I just updated my OP with my current code. Thanks again!

Comment: see the very end of my post, it's possible that springboard is cutting you off. maybe you should try to save them earlier

Comment: Do your imageViews all have unique `tag` numbers?  If they all have tag `0`, tag filenames will be the same.  Also, build your array of imageViews at design time.  [Using iOS 4′s IBOutletCollection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/) may help there.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong.  The immediate problem follows `for (UIImageView *imageView in self.array) {`.  It uses `self.imageView` (property of the viewController) instead of `imageView` (for loop control variable).

Comment: @Dondragmer Thanks a lot Dondragmer. Yes all of my imageViews have unique tag numbers, starting at 1.

Comment: @JustinAmberson Alright thanks, I will try that now. Should I create my own method, like this: `- (void)appShouldSaveData:(UIApplication *)application ` and copy everything in appDidEnterBackground and paste it in my new method?

Comment: @OralB: Why not save data whenever a change happens?  When a new image is picked, save that particular image.  Also, did you read 3 comments back, about properties and for loop control variables?

Comment: @Dondragmer Yes sir, but unfortunately that somewhat went over my head, sorry I'm still very novice. So, I just added a save button to my view, and attached it to a new method I wrote. I copied everything in appDidEnterBackground and pasted it in my new method, along with an NSLog to show that it fired correctly, and it did. But, none of the files are saving. It used to save the first one, but not anymore. Very strange.

Comment: @OralB: You'd better edit the question with your latest code.  Don't leave the old versions in there; they'll be in the revision history if enyone needs to check them.  Do keep an **Edit** header to acknowledge that you've changed the question.

Comment: @Dondragmer Alright thanks, I just updated my OP with my current code.

Comment: @JustinAmberson Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out, I appreciate it. I marked your answer as correct, and it will let me send you the bounty in 15 hours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [NSbundle Mainbundel]  to store that images.

**To get path**

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I tried your code above but it didn't work, so I reverted back to the code in my OP. Do you know how my imagePickerController method, appDidEnterBackground and viewDidLoad should look?

Comment: slight nitpick, the first sentence about using [NSBundle mainBundle] is incorrect,as it returns the path to the .app bundle. iOS does not allow apps to write to the .app bundle

Answer (score 1):

First, there's still a problem in your for loop.

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in self.array) {
    NSInteger tag = self.imageView.tag;
    UIImage *image = self.imageView.image;
    // ...
}
```

Before you make any other changes, you must understand why.  `imageView` is your *for loop control variable*, which changes on each iteration through the loop.  `self.imageView` is a different thing.  It is the *first of the 10 imageViews attached to your viewController*.  Every time this loop cycles, it looks at the first imageView, and only the first.

As for why saving doesn't work, it's probably because the arrays elsewhere aren't working.  Add some logging to make sure there's something in the array, and that it has as many elements as you expect.

```
-(IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    // Log to make sure the views expected have previously been stored.
    // If the array is empty, or shorter than expected, the problem is elsewhere.
    NSLog(@"Image view array before saving = %@", self.array);

    for (UIImageView *imageViewToSave in self.array) {

        NSInteger tag = imageViewToSave.tag;
        UIImage *image = imageViewToSave.image;
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image%i.png",tag];

        NSString *imagePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

        // Log the image and path being saved.  If either of these are nil, nothing will be written.
        NSLog(@"Saving %@ to %@", image, imagePath);

        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO];
    }
    NSLog(@"Save Button Pressed");
}
```

Comment: I'll just add - if you get a solution out of this, the bounty should still go to Justin Amberson for getting started on the problem.

Comment: Awesome thank you very much, that was extremely helpful. The NSLog stated that the array was null, so it appears that the problem is elsewhere. I think should probably just start another question regarding that. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Comment: If the array is null, it is never being constructed.  You probably took out the `self.array = [[self.user objectForKey:@"images"]mutableCopy];`, or mayble it's now returning null.  Anyway, in `viewDidLoad`, include `self.array = [NSMutableArray array];`.

Comment: Awesome that did the trick, thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I've been working on this for a week and never would of gotten it without your help!