# how to delete images / file from file system?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I get the idea of saving and loading from file system in ios from:
[How Can I Save This Array of Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099233/how-can-i-save-this-array-of-images)

can anyone tell me how to delete or remove it from file system?

Answer (score 10):

You can do it using NSDefaultManager

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pngFilePath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:pngFilePath error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: imagePath error: nil];
```